# Android app working on 2.3 but not on 4.0

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-2.1-eclair

Ok, I have been working on a Android application for a while. It's basicaly a RSS reciever. I use RSS to check the news, weather forecast, TV schedule and Horoscope.

Everything was fine while I was testing it on Android 2.3.3, 2.3.6 and even on 2.1; but when I sent it to my friend who has Android 4.0 it did not work. I was suspicious so I tested it on emulator. Nor 4.0, nor 4.1 Emulators can run it. Here I provide Manifest and one class. If anybody knows how to fix this, that will be great.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="XXX.XXXXX.XXX"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Vodic"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pocetna" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Pomoc"
        android:label="@string/m_tel_vodi_za_odlu_ne"
        ></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Pomocna"
        android:label="@string/m_tel_vodi_za_odlu_ne"
        ></activity>
    .
    .
    .

    <activity
        android:name=".TvRasporedTreca"
        android:label="@string/m_tel_vodi_za_odlu_ne"
        ></activity>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Needed to check when the network connection changes -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

And here's one class:

```
public class Vodic extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pocetna);
    Button tv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Button vijesti = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vijesti);
    Button horoskop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.horoskop);
    Button vremenska_prognoza = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vremenska_prognoza);
    Button o_aplikaciji = (Button)findViewById(R.id.o_aplikaciji);
    Button pomoc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pomoc);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent fy=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TV_Raspored.class);
            startActivity(fy);
        }
    });

    .
    .
    .

    pomoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent fy=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Pomoc.class);
            startActivity(fy);
        }
    });

}

public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_pocetna, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

So, to sum up. It works on 2.1 and 2.3.3 but doesn't on 4.0 and 4.1 . I have no Idea what's wrong.. so if anybody knows, please help..

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Is there any logcat you can provide. What is the error you are seeing? Does it fail to install? Does it crash on first run?

Comment: Does it gets installed? DO you see any error in logcat?

Comment: "it doesn't work" ? what does that even means ?

Comment: please give us the logcat log :)

Comment: the common problem experienced which shows this type of o/p is the n/w on ui thread error which happens from 3.0 + in net related apps if the n/w related operation is done in the main thread instead of an async task

Comment: I think this is maybe a thread problem,can you give me your network class?

Comment: Can you give me your Logcat message?

Comment: Ok, as you needed more info, I provided log and more classes this time. I made a new question. Please look at it: [QUESTION-HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963646/android-app-cant-start-on-android-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

From Android 3.x and onward Google has added some checks that generate errors if your application employs very bad practices.
Without a log it is hard to confirm, but the most likely scenario is that you are making network operations in the core of your activities, generating a NetworkOnUIThread exception.
It is NOT a bug in the Android framework. The problem is that your activities run in the main thread, ie the UI thread.
So when you make a network call in an Activity, the whole UI freezes until you get an answer (or a timeout); which is something that you absolutely want to avoid.
An easy solution to this issue is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) : it is an easy to implement built-in solutions to make operations in a secondary thread.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Please look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963646/android-app-cant-start-on-android-4-0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963646/android-app-cant-start-on-android-4-0) ... I added more information to this question. Logs and more classes